# Creating jdbc connection pools on glassfish with default properties using asadmin

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, glassfish

I would like to create a jdbc connection pool from the command line --- doing it through the browser all the time is driving me crazy as it is such a tedious process. I've used the command

```
    asadmin create-jdbc-connection-pool
      --datasourceclassname com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
      --restype javax.sql.DataSource
      --property user=root:password=test:DatabaseName=test:ServerName=localhost:port=3306
    the-pool
```

with success. However, it creates a connection pool with only the properties that are specified in the command.  When I use the administration console at *localhost:4848* to create a connection pool, the default number of "additional parameters" seem to be in the region of 171 properties.  I'm assuming that the console is enacting a default property flag.  Does anyone know how I might modify the command to get a more comprehensive list of properties?  I've consulted the [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4495/6nfv4mkhr/index.html) docs for pool administration but have had no joy and my shoddy installation of glassfish rendered `asadmin`'s help pages defunct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using the command posted in the question successfully for the past few months.  There appears to be no need to set any of the additional properties. However, I use `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` instead of MysqlDataSource for the sake of performance (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582052/what-is-difference-between-mysqldatasource-and-mysqconnectionpoolldatasource)).

Upon creation of the pool, the jdbc resource is created by

```
asadmin create-jdbc-resource --connectionpoolid the-pool jdbc/the-pool
```